# How to draw dots in a picture in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I want to draw the following graph:
[image]

I have written the following code

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb,tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        0[fill=blue],  1[fill=red], 2[fill=red]
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black,] (0) at (0,0) {$1$};    
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (1) at  (5,-1) {$n$};  
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (2) at  (4,-2) {$m$};  
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (5) at (5,1) {$3$}; 
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (6) at (4,2) {$2$}; 
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (7) at (3,3) {$1$};  
        \draw (0) -- (1);  
        \draw (0) -- (2);  
        \draw (0) -- (5);  
        \draw (0) -- (6);  
        \draw (0) -- (7);  
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \label{Fig1}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

But I am unable to produce the dots in place of the vertices. How to get my desired output? Can someone please help me out?

Comment: What's the first line of your TikZ picture supposed to do? You can draw a dotted line by using [`\draw[dotted]`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-actions#sec-15.3.2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Adaptations

- removed unused packages
- define a style `mynode` for the nodes
- use `\foreach` to do draw the nodes and lines
- draw dashed line with `bend left=20`
- use polar coordinates `(<angle>:<distance>)`

#### Code

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    mynode/.style={circle, draw}
]
    \node[mynode] (1) at (0,0) {$1$};
    \foreach \i in {2, ..., 4} {
        \node[mynode] (\i) at ($(1)+({90-\i*15}:40mm)$) {$\i$};
    }
    \node[mynode] (5) at ($(1)+(-30:40mm)$) {$t$};
    \node[mynode] (6) at ($(1)+(-45:40mm)$) {$t+1$};
    % solid lines
    \foreach \i in {2, ..., 6} {
        \draw (1) -- (\i);
    }
    % dashed & dotted lines
    \draw[dashed, shorten <=3mm, shorten >=3mm] (4) to[bend left=20] (5);
    \foreach \i in {1, ..., 3} {
        \draw[dotted, shorten >=4mm] (1) -- ++({30-\i*15}:40mm);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image]

Comment: Wow! thats excellent, thank you so much dear, lots of love for you